# Печать из питона на принтер

Tags: python, python-3.x, печать

Делаю одну вещь которая должна грузить из .html документов определенный текст в bdSqlite3.

```
def sqlite3_simple_example_create_db():
    con = sqlite3.connect("./operation.db")
    cur = con.cursor()

    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("HTML files", "*.html; *.htm"),
                                                  ("TXT files", "*.txt"),
                                                  ("All files", "*.*")))
    file_input = open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-16-le')
    s = file_input.read(105)
    print(1.0, s)


    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS core_fes(id integer primary key, file_name TEXT, Reports TEXT, Model TEXT, Object TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO core_fes(file_name, Reports, Model, Object) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                (file_name, s1, s3, s5))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

sqlite3_simple_example_create_db()
```

Предыдущий вопрос решен, теперь встал вопрос печати.

```
os.startfile(file_name, "print")
```

выводит на печать весь файл. Но у меня из файла уже получены

```
file_input = open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-16-le')
        s = file_input.read(105)
        print(1.0, s)
        s1 = file_input.read(44)  # Reports
        s2 = file_input.read(192)
        print(1.0, s2)
        s3 = file_input.read(8)  # Model
        s4 = file_input.read(88)
        print(1.0, s4)
        s5 = file_input.read(32)  # Object
```

С помощью чего можно вывести на печать еще?

Answer (score 1):

> С помощью чего можно вывести на печать еще?

Например:

```
import logging
from sys import stdout

# 1
print("Hello")

# 2
stdout.write("Hello")

# 3
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.info("Hello")
```

Про печать на принтер. Гораздо эффективнее будет создать новый файл с актуальными данными, вместо попытки печатать куски из переменных.

Comment: сам виноват не указал, что на принтер печать

Comment: типо результат сохранять как темп файл, а его вывод на печать?

Comment: именно так. потому что на данный момент все данные разбросаны. если вы хотите напечатать все за один раз, то вы и хранить все должны в одном месте.